# Jasmine how to use done()?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm trying to wrap my head around `done()` so I can test an asynchronous web service call. The documentation from [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html) and others don't make sense to me, I can't see where the code goes, where the test for completion goes, or where the actual Jasmine tests go. They don't even use any asynchronous calls.

This question previously asked about `runs()` and `waitsFor()`, they've been deprecated in 2.0, apparently because ["It's much simpler."](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jasmine-js/Q_4lyEWrZKI) using `done()`! In any case, on my version 2.6, using `done()` anywhere in the code brings up a reference error that it isn't defined, so I'm really not sure what's going on.

This is the code I'd like to be able to adapt. The code to call is `helper.send(url, data, params);` and the code is done when `response !== null`.

```
it ('should be able to invoke a web service with POST as the HTTP method', function() {
    // Data
    let data = {name: 'StackOverflow'};
    // POST
    let params = {method: 'POST'};
    // This call is asynchronous
    // The URL just echoes back the get and post parameters
    request.send(url, data, params);
    // Need to wait for response !== null
    // ...
    // Can now resume tests
    expect(response.post.name).toEqual('StackOverflow');
});
```

If anyone can help with how to reorganize this to work with `done()`, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: does your request do a `promise` or callback?

Comment: With a callback, it copies everything to `response`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your function that handles the response into the `it` body. Things get reorganized a bit:

```
// *** Pass "done" in the function, Jasmine automagically knows what to do with it
it ('should be able to invoke a web service with POST as the HTTP method', function(done) {
    // *** Local callback to use here
    let localCallback = function(/* arguments */) {
        // *** Local copy of response
        let response = null;
        // *** Copy your stuff into response
        ...
        // *** Moved your tests here
        // Can now resume tests
        expect(response.post.name).toEqual('StackOverflow');     
        // *** Let Jasmine know this "it" is finished  
        done();
    }
    // *** Do your setup here to use the local callback above
    let request = ...(localCallback);
    // Data
    let data = {name: 'StackOverflow'};
    // POST
    let params = {method: 'POST'};
    // This call is asynchronous
    // The URL just echoes back the get and post parameters
    request.send(url, data, params);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, the comments make it much clearer how it works.

Comment: Buddy - what happens if I don't use done? Would Jasmine continue to the next spec or mark this one as pass (because there is nothing to expect after request.send) without waiting for the localCallback to run?

Answer (score 2):

If your `request` is promise based you would do something like this:

```js
it ('should be able to invoke a web service with POST as the HTTP method',
  function(done) {
    // Data
    let data = {name: 'StackOverflow'};
    // POST
    let params = {method: 'POST'};
    // This call is asynchronous
    // The URL just echoes back the get and post parameters
    request.send(url, data, params).then(
      funciton(response) {
        expect(response.post.name).toEqual('StackOverflow');
        done();
      }
    ).catch(
      function(err) {
        done(new Error(err));
      }
    );
  }
);
```

This will only run the `expect` when the data is returned.

`done` is called with no params to indicate that your code is finished.

`done` is called with an `Error` object to indicate that something failed. The message of the `Error` object should tell what failed.

Comment: +1 for describing how/when `done` is called with parameters. Even the official documentation seems to lack this. I was quite confused when testing async code using promises and this was always failing tests `.then(done)` (correct is `.then(result => done())`)

Comment: Yeah. Calling `.then(done)` will pass the resolved data into `done` and passing anything into `done` is telling it that an error has occurred. So calling `.then(result => done())` is how to tell `done` that no error has occurred.

Comment: what if done() isn't recognized in my test cases? I can't seem to find any documentation on it.